# I stored API data to a state and tried to pass it to another component as prop, but it’s behaving differently there

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I stored API data to a state and tried to pass it to another component as prop, but it’s behaving differently there.

I'm trying to pass the animeList data to the AnimeCard component, but when I start typing in the input, it shows undefined or previous search result as many times as I press something in the console and on submit it shows two arrays of the value.

```js
const SearchBar = () => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState()

    const animeSearch = async (query) => {
        const temp = await fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?     q=${query}&order_by=title&sort=asc&limit=10`)
        .then(res => res.json())

        //console.log(temp.results) it works here
        setAnimeList(temp.results)
    }

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        animeSearch(search)
    }

    return (
        <div className='center'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSearch}>
                <input placeholder='search' type='search' value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <AnimeCard animeList={animeList} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

```js
const AnimeCard = ({animeList}) => {
    //trouble here
    console.log(animeList)
}

export default AnimeCard
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JAfF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was causing trouble, because I didn't set my useState to the array:

```js
const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState([])
```

That was it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Codesandbox for you.
[Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feather-lr5ywb?file=/src/index.js).

You have many problems with your code:

1. Why does it show `undefined` many times? -

- When the component (SearchBar) renders, your `AnimeCard` component will render. The time it rendered, you did not set anything to the `animeList` state.
- Why did I show many times? A React component will rerender if there is any state change. `search` is one of your states. Every time you type something, it changes, which causes a **rerender**.
- How can you fix it? Add a condition to it, like what I did in line `31`.

2. Why did it log many times when you got the result? -

- you have React's `StricMode` component wrapped in file *index.js*
- fix:

  - Delete `<StrictMode>` in file *index.js* which causes a double render.
  - you should *console.log* inside the useEffect hook.

PS: Advice: don’t forget to pass a default value for the state

Comment: and also dont forget to pass default value for state.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for adding important info; edit & update your post instead.